# Electric Field Due to Large Sheet

Tags: electricity, gauss-law, calculus

In a recent lecture, our physics professor was going over the Gauss's law derivation for the electric field due to a large (flat) sheet using
$$\oint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=\frac{q_{in}}{\epsilon_0}$$
However, he made the assumption that (in the following diagram) $\vec{E}(z)=\vec{E}(-z)=\vec{E}_{total}$. I don't quite get why this is...shouldn't the proper conclusion be $\vec{E}(z)=\vec{E}(-z)=\frac{1}{2}\vec{E}_{total}$ **or** $\vec{E}(z)+\vec{E}(-z)=\vec{E}_{total}$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct relationship is $|\vec{E}(z)|=|\vec{E}(-z)|=|\vec{E}_{\rm total}|$ where $E_{\rm total}$ the magnitude of the field on either side of the conducting plane and it is a statement that the fields on either side of the plane with total surface charge density $\sigma$ are symmetrical.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- A plane can be thought of as a 2D slice that provides a view of the
  electric field (E-field) in a particular direction.
- In this case, the E-field has a constant value and is unidirectional,
  extending from the negative-z direction to the positive-z direction.
- This E-field represents the entirety of the field or a planar field,
  in contrast to the localized nature of a point charge.
- The charges responsible for generating this E-field are situated on
  two parallel planes, which can be visualized as a small window into
  the overall system.